# Bluetooth Headset - Windows 10 - appearing as Bluetooth hands-free

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone, wireless-headset

I recently bough the following product from Amazon:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B019ZEHA36/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Essentially it works in terms of connecting etc and bonding via Bluetooth.

The issue lies with windows picking this up as a Bluetooth hands-free device, see icon below.
[Hands-free ICON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXTbM.png)

This I think is part of the problem, furthermore, under sound control there is the following options, Stereo and Hands-free.
[Playback devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTaB4.png)

Please for the time being ignore that the headset is disconnected.

Under recording devices its the following: [Recording devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A2qN.png)

Putting all of this together I have the following options:

- use the Handsfree option but suffer with low quality sound through headset (channel 1)
- Use the Stereo as default - which means good quality sound (channel 2) - but also means that the device no longer has any Mic associated with it.

Furthermore, searching across the web, it was noted to disable hands free "under services, under device manager". However this just means that it defaults to the Stereo every time and the hands free (which includes a Mic) does not work.

I have also connected a USB blutooth device (running V10) as supposed to the internal, but still not luck. I have re-installed the device multiple times with reboots and removing it from devices.

Please can someone help here with any suggestion, I am very close to just returning this item as its not working properly...

Comment: This is how the device and its driver were designed to work. I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: I wouldnt have a problem, its just that the sound is so muffled... like listening to someone underwater :)